# Suggested edits: do questions need both [javascript] and [jquery] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I've run across a couple suggested edits today that only add a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag to a question already marked with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery). The question seemed valid and in no need of edits (content or formatting) but I'm really unsure if this should be an accept or reject. I know the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag says the following:

> ... Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected

which to me implies that if [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) is present, then maybe [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) isn't necessary on the question, but I could be wrong. I've also heard arguments for both sides of this issue:

1. Both [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) are necessary.
2. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) isn't needed if [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) is present.

I know this seems pointless and somewhat trivial, but I just want to be consistent in my reviews.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One of the main purposes of the tags is to rapidly find the right questions to answer based on the knowledge of the user who's browsing the site. For example, assume I'm an experienced programmer in JavaScript, and I want to find all the questions concerning JavaScript: I will add [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to my favourites and browse it when I want to answer some question.

Now, if some user only uses [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) on their question, I will not be able to find it under [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), because there isn't such tag. I will then lose the opportunity to answer all the questions that are only tagged with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

*"But you could always take a look at [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) too..."* Yes, I could, but jQuery is not the only existing famous JavaScript library, and checking for any other library would become impossible, I cannot waste all of my time looking for any question which is not tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), but still concerns JavaScript.

So, in the end, and IMHO this is valid for every programming language (not just JavaScript), the asker should always include the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, and, when the problem also concerns a specific library, the relative tag too (e.g., [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)). So, as a reviewer, **you should accept suggested edits which add the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag to questions tagged only with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)**. It is also safe then, to assume that someone tagging only with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) doesn't want to use any other external library, and solve the problem in plain JavaScript (although you can always ask in the comments), and someone tagging with both [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) would like to receive a jQuery based answer, if possible.

Comment: Sounds good! I hope more people read this so they can also suggest the edits correctly. Thanks for the input.

Comment: NONONONO! This would just piss off all the JS developers that don't want jQuery questions. If you want to answer questions about jQuery, add the jQuery tag, it only takes a second. If we scale this up, most questions about frameworks would have their respective languages tags, *just because*, when such knowledge isn't actually necessary. Also, all questions tagged with javascript are assumed to want a javascript answer. If you are wondering how bind something to a selector using `.bind()` API, a JS developer can't help you, since they may not know anything about jQuery nor the API.

Comment: @Braiam "all questions tagged with javascript are assumed to want a javascript answer" - unless it's also tagged with jquery... Also, can't you just unfollow the jQuery tag if you don't want to see those questions? (maybe that feature was introduced after your comment was posted)

Comment: @pushkin but if I want to see js questions I'll be shown those with and without the jquery tag.

Comment: @Braiam Ah I meant like how on the homepage, you see the questions tagged with what you're following excluding the questions with tags that you've explicitly unfollowed. But if you're searching for the tag, you can exclude jquery by doing something like this: [javascript] -[jquery]

Answer (score 11):

It purely depends on context. In general, every question needs more jQuery and the easiest way to accomplish that is to add the jQuery tag.

Jokes aside, the tagging should relate to the material. Sometimes the only issue in the question is with relation to the jQuery API. These methods include things like `.hide()`, `.find()`, `.closest()`, `.click()`, `.bind()`, `.on()`, `.addClass()`, `.toggle()`, hopefully the point is made. In that case, the jQuery tag is definitely relevant.

So now, what about the JavaScript tag? This depends on the use of the jQuery API. If the *use* of the jQuery API also includes JavaScript more than the simple constructs of a callback and some more jQuery API calls then it can be relevant. It is especially relevant if aspects of JavaScript are being questioned such as using the native API. The native API and use can relate to things like the basic "types" in the language (string, number, boolean, function, object) - basically terms and behaviors defined in the ECMAScript standard.

tldr; Not always, but often. The extra tag does not harm the post, but it can be trivial if the post is short and only contains a very narrow reference to jQuery.

Comment: I had a funny feeling this would be a context-based answer :P But this makes sense, and I will review accordingly.

Comment: @TimLewis - I think Marco makes a good point too, in that if an answerer is trying to find a post to answer, it helps to have the relevant language tagged as well.

Comment: This is a more sane policy. Not anybody following the javascript tag would know anything about jQuery API's. If you are doing pure jQuery, only the jquery tag, pure JS, only javascript tag, mixing both, both tags.

Answer (score 2):

If Option 2 (i.e. that [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) **isn't** needed) is deemed better by the Community, then the Wiki-excerpt for [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) should most probably be edited.

Currently, this opens with:

> jQuery is a JavaScript library. Consider also adding the JavaScript
> tag. …

As for reviewing suggested edits: While that advice remains in the tag-Wiki excerpt, I think it is fine for users to add the tag to jQuery questions that don't have it. Rejecting the suggestion on the grounds that it is adding "irrelevant tags" strikes me as both inconsistent and unfair.