# Adding more general version of tags

Tags: discussion, review-queues

When reviewing I see a lot of edits that propose a more generalized version of already added tags.

For example people add [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to a question already tagged with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) (a JavaScript framework) or they add[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) when[python-2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6) is already there.

Should those edits be accepted?

EDIT 1: [Should I not use the generic tag if my solution is limited to a specific version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version)

Is it good practice to add generalized tags?

EDIT 2: [Suggested edits: do questions need both [javascript] and [jquery] tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290244/suggested-edits-do-questions-need-both-javascript-and-jquery-tags)

Comment: IMHO, yes. I keep track of [tag:python]. I'm not going to keep track of [tag:python], [tag:python-2.7], and [tag:python-3.x]; especially as a lot (but not all) questions in [tag:python-2.7] are *also* in [tag:python], so I'd have to mentally filter those out.

Comment: This is what I feel, too. It would be tedious to track all version specific tags. But what about general technologies like `javascript`. Those are used in so many contexts (`jquery`, `nodejs`, `angularjs`, you name it,...) that it would flood the list of tags.

Comment: @carpet Tag wildcards are supported, so you can favorite or search for `[python*]` or `[python-*]`.

Comment: @CodyGray That answer does not solve my question about general technologies.

Comment: @CodyGray: Tag wildcards don't really hep for [tag:jquery] > [tag:javascript]. `[j*]` is kinda broad.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "general technologies." Martijin's answer specifically addresses adding more general versions of tags to questions that already have a more specific tag. If you are looking specifically for guidance on adding [javascript] tags to [jquery] questions, then you could search for that, and [ye shall find](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290244/suggested-edits-do-questions-need-both-javascript-and-jquery-tags).

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't proposing wildcards as a general solution here. I definitely agree with Martijn that the generic language/framework tag should appear on the question as well. I was just addressing Carpetsmoker's comment about how he keeps track of questions.

Comment: You might also want to look at the posts under [meta-tag:tag-hierarchy], most are on MSE though.