# Should I also attach the parent tag when my question is about the child tag?

Tags: support, tags

As you know, I have to attach a least one tag to the question before publishing. All tags aren't on the same level. Some of them the covers the other ones. Consider the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag. It covers the [codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter) tag. In other word, all question about CodeIgniter framework are related to the PHP. Because that's a library of PHP.

It's also true for {[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)} or {[sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)} or lots of other similar tags. OK well, when I have a question about the *child* (like [codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter)), should I also attach the *parent* tag (like [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)) ?

Or when I'm investigating a suggested edit, should I approve/reject the ones which have added just a parent tag for the question?

Comment: Related question (for the reviewing part) [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290244/suggested-edits-do-questions-need-both-javascript-and-jquery-tags).

Comment: More related discussion [Am I right in removing the \[github\] tag from (some) \[git\] questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326872)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hierarchical relationship between tags. Either or the tag should be added or it shouldn't. Tags works as separated entities and one tag doesn't ever imply other, and it should be kept that way. Tags aren't keywords, nor they are supposed to be used like turtles: all the way down, or up. If your question is about mysql, tag it as mysql. If it has nothing to do with mysql, then don't use the mysql tag. Using mysql doesn't imply that you should use the mysql tag, it should be a non-tangential part of your problem. Simple.