# My edit didn't make a drastic change, why was it rejected?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I just made this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13039945), but it was rejected.

The OP was getting changing tab, and leaving a page mixed up (which even confused me). I tried to helpfully edit that in to make it clearer, but it was rejected.

Here's a snippet from the unedited post:

> I have to display message which warns user before leaving page without saving changes. An url in the browser does not change in this process because *user changes only a tab.*

Emphasis mine. Here's my change:

> I have to display message which warns user before changing tab without saving changes. An url in the browser does not change in this process because user changes only a tab.

I also added the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, as this is about JavaScript, if only because [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) is a JavaScript framework.

Was this too drastic, or was it not properly reviewed?

The original poster even clarified later on what they meant:

> Thanks for your answer but our system is SPA (single page application) and warning dialog should appear *when the users selects another tab.* Thats why the url does not changes so the event "beforeunload" is not fired. Is there any way to trigger this event or angulars event e.g.(locationChangeStart)

The two rejection messages say:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post.

And

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question.

I disagree with both, what can I do?

Comment: "(which even confused me)" if you are confused how can you possibly clarify the OPs intention? Are you a mind reader/psychic?

Comment: It is worth noting that the OP added this additional requirement in a comment under your answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill because I didn't read the post thoroughly first. The OP clarified I connected later,  as well

Comment: Anyway this looks like a classical XY problem. The OP wants to prevent their user from switching away from their application: then install the application in kiosk mode.

Comment: The review was a split decision, but they largely did not like you adding the [javascript] tag.  It is just not necessary.  [angularjs] is a big tag with lots of Q+A, javascript is assumed and everybody that is an expert in [angularjs] already knows the language.  But not everybody that knows [javascript] knows angular.

Comment: @HansPassant, but the question is really about [tag:javascript] not [tag:angularjs]. An angular expert might not be able to answer the question,  but a JavaScript one could.

Comment: @HansPassant Also see this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290244/suggested-edits-do-questions-need-both-javascript-and-jquery-tags/290246#290246)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>The wording of the question suggests that the OP him/herself is a little confused. The correct action here is to ask for clarification in a comment, not suggesting an edit. We might end up with a good answer that doesn't even help to solve the OP's problem at all.</s>

The edit might got rejected (unfairly) because reviewers only see the post *itself*, not the comments underneath. So for them it is hard to get a good view of what's going on. The only thing that helps is writing this clearly in the edit summary. That might mean that the summary is to be longer than the actual edit itself.

As for the tag: the consensus seems to be that adding [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to questions concerning a JavaScript framework like Angular is [allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290246/4751173), so that rejection reason is not applicable.

Comment: The additional information was provided in a comment under the OP's answer.

Comment: I did ask for clarification